# Symlinks and permissions in backup archives

Tags: linux, backup, tar, data-recovery, file-copy

I installed Linux on another computer and I want to move my `/home` directory to that computer. I want to back up that directory with any file permission, symlinks etc.

How should I do it? Are there any parameters for tar gzip?

Comment: Rsync is maybe better than tar...

Comment: why? what's the difference? what is the command?

Comment: Sorry I read to quickly your question. I you want a backup, you are right, tar is better. If you want to deploy a new PC, a rsync copy from one host to another (with just -a option) is better than doing a tar and explode it on the other host

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you mean you want to include the files that the symlinks point to, use `-h`.

```
tar -chzf foo.tar.gz directory/
```

Permissions and ownership are preserved by default.  If you just want to include the symlinks as symlinks, leave out `-h`. Small `-z` is for gzip.

This is all spelled out in `man tar`; you can search for terms (such as "symlink") in `man` via the forward-slash key <kbd>/</kbd>.

---

When you extract the archive (`tar -xzf foo.tar.gz`), ownership *will only be preserved if you unpack as root*, otherwise, all the files will be owned by you.   This is a feature, since otherwise it would often be impossible for a normal user to access files in an archive they (e.g.) download.  Modal permissions (read/write/execute) will remain the same. If as a regular user you want the ownership preserved anyway, you can use the `-p` switch (so `tar -xzpf foo.tar.gz`).

However, there is a catch.

File ownership is actually stored as a number, not a name; the system reports names by correlating them with a value from `/etc/passwd`.  You can find the number corresponding to your user name with:

```
grep yourusername < /etc/passwd
```

Which will print something like:

```
piotek:x:1001:1001::/home/piotek:/bin/bash
```

The first number is your user number, the second one is your group number (they are usually the same).  The other fields are explained in `man 5 passwd` (note the `5`).

As a consequence, if you tar up some files and unpack them on another system as root, or using `-p` (so that ownership is preserved), and there is a user on that system whose user number is 1001, those files will be owned by that user, even if their name is not `piotek` (and even if there is a `piotek` user on the system with a different corresponding number).

The `tar` man page is a little confusing in this regard, since it refers to the `-p` switch as involving *file permissions*.  This is a common *nix ambiguity in a context where the state of the read/write/execute bits are referred to as *mode*.