# How to copy files from linux rhel6 to another rhel6 (which are not connected)?

Tags: rhel, cp, ftp, zip, ln

How to copy files or folders from linux rhel6 server to another (which are not connected) with same file or folder properties (especially symlinks) using zip?

1. The only way is FTP to server1 and copy store in local (win10)
2. from local to FTP to server2 and copy that to server2

Basically preserving the folder structure, Permissions, files, softlinks and everything how we can do that?

Please help.

Comment: Hi @pLumo , the servers are not connected to each other. trying to copy folder /etc/rc.d from a server(linux rhel6) to local(win10) and then from local to place in a damaged server(linux rhel6). so need exact permissions, folder structure, ownership of files and symlinks or softlinks. please help with any commands that can do the task.

Comment: This answere will help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119842/254422

Comment: Only FTP and Windows as middle man. I somehow doubt that this is possible ... Any chance of getting sftp / ssh connection to both servers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symlinks and permissions in backup archives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119841/symlinks-and-permissions-in-backup-archives)